# Oracle session info via MS Access database

Tags: oracle, vba, ms-access, oracle10g, adodb

We have many Access DBs that connect to, and perform various tasks around our Oracle DBs using an ODBC connection for the statically linked tables (using Access' Jet engine)

When I query the sessions on Oracle, they are all listed against simply 'MSACCESS.exe', and so far I haven't found a way to find out which Access DB is behind the session from a DBA standpoint.

Using ADODB, I can, for individual processes/connections, use a call to Oracle's dbms_application_info package to set client specific details.

Is there any way to do something similar for the underlying connection set up for the linked tables?

In case it matters, the Access DBs are v2010, and the Oracle DB is 10gR1.

Comment: ODBC is very generic, thus you may miss functions  which are more specific

Comment: Did you consider using [SQL trace files](http://www.orafaq.com/node/14) and identifying it in [current session](https://blogs.oracle.com/sysdba/entry/how_to_identify_trace_file_in)?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Oracle docs for a ODBC connection string.

In Access, I use this code to create a connection string for a linked table.

```
Public Function dbCon(ServerName As String, _
                  DataBaseName As String, _
                  Optional UserID As String, _
                  Optional USERpw As String, _
                  Optional APP As String = "InvocieProgram", _
                  Optional WSID As String = "RobertPC") As String

' returns a SQL server conneciton string

dbCon = "ODBC;DRIVER=" & SQLDRIVER & ";" & _
       "SERVER=" & ServerName & ";" & _
       "DATABASE=" & DataBaseName & ";"
       If UserID <> "" Then
          dbCon = dbCon & "UID=" & UserID & ";" & "PWD=" & USERpw & ";"
       End If
       dbCon = dbCon & _
       "APP=" & APP & ";" & _
       "WSID=" & WSID & ";" & _
       "Network=DBMSSOCN"

End Function
```

If you look close there is a APP and also a WSID that can BOTH be used by the SQL profiler. I not looked at Oracle, but there is likely several “optional” settings that you can use/set in the connection string. With above, then the SQL profiler tools will show the workstation, and the APP setting. While the above is for SQL Server, I would guess that Oracle also allows some of these additional paramters. And besides, you likely want to use some re-link code to set the connection strings and thus you don't have to configure each workstation manually for the application to connect. So the re-link code is a "one time" on startup - each additional startup you don't have to re-link nor re-set the connection strings with the additional APP and workstation ID that ODBC strings allow. These settings don't really do anything of value in terms of the connection, but they do show up in the SQL profiler -  you can thus hunt down and view the SQL server logs and they will show the application.